# Change Page data based on selected item

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a dashboard with a couple of charts and a dropdownlist. I want to be able to refresh the data in all the charts based on the selected item.  each of the charts looks like :

```
<div class="sparkline-container">
  @(Html.Kendo().Chart<DemoCash.Web.Models.KPIViewModel>()
    .Name("CashUtil")
    .Theme("default")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "height: 150px;" })
    .SeriesColors(new string[] { "#ff6800", "#c20000" })
    .Legend(legend => legend.Visible(false))
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea.Background("transparent"))
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("onCashUtilDataBound"))
    .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("CashUtilByBranch", "Dashboard")))
    .Series(series => {series.Donut("CashUtilization","BranchId").Padding(0);})
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true)
      .Template("#= dataItem.BranchName #: #=dataItem.CashUtilization # %")
    )
  )
  <div id="CashUtilizationNoData" class="overlay">
    <div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

while the dropdownlist is :

```
  <div id="brnfilter">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("cbobrnfilter")
      .DataTextField("BranchName")
      .DataValueField("BranchId")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:250px" })
      .DataSource( 
        datasource => {datasource.Read(read =>{read.Action("GetRegionBranches", "Branch");})
        .ServerFiltering(true);})
    )
 </div>
```

There are also other chart types on the page.

Comment: It looks like the data are read on serverside. If so, you have to create a hidden form read the dropdown value and submit the data to same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add javascript event listener function to the drop down list. For example:

```
Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Events(e => { e.Cascade("someJsFunction"); })
.Name("cbobrnfilter")...
```

See other kendo drop down events [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist). Then in your js function `someJsFunction` change the data source according to selected value and refresh the chart:

```
$('#CashUtil').data().kendoChart.dataSource.read();
$('#CashUtil').data().kendoChart.refresh();
```

Comment: My new function looks like :function onCriteriaChange() {
        var chart1 = $("#FirstChart").data("kendoChart"),
startDate = $("#StartDate").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            endDate = $("#EndDate").data("kendoDatePicker"), 
myfilter = { 'BranchCode': branchCode.value(), 'startDate': startDate.value(), 'endDate': endDate.value() };
chart1.dataSource.read(myfilter);
$('#FirstChart').data().kendoChart.refresh();

}